# Which method to POST JS object to server side (PHP)?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to POST some manipulated data to Server side using jQuery Ajax.

I have already captured required data in a JavaScript Object like:

```
var person = {
               firstName:"John", 
               lastName:"Doe", 
               age:50, 
               eyeColor:"blue"
            };
```

What is the best, secure and appropriate method on POSTing this object (Serialize, FormData, etc)?

```
var user = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: person,
    ...
```

or

```
var user = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: person.serialize(),
    ...
```

Comment: have you tried either? what kind of results have you seen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just pass your person object directly to `data` as shown in the examples in  [`$.ajax docs`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

```
var user = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: person,
    ...
```

[`serialize()`](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) is used to create data string from form elements based on their `name` and value and is not used on object literals

Then in php you would receive using same property keys as in your person object

```
$first = $_POST['firstName'];
```